# How is it possible to use the Diablo III Wizard skills Magic Weapon and Familiar at the same time?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Recently I saw the following profile:

[image: Wizard with Magic Weapon and Familiar]

I am wondering how it is possible to use Magic Weapon and Familiar at the same time. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Still most definitely a duplicate, I feel.  This now links to it, so everyone should be helped, whether they know about Elective Mode or not.

Comment: You're asking about the same thing, from the other side.  There's no point in fragmenting the information into two different questions, just because it asks from a different direction.  You're asking about elective mode, even if you don't know what it's called.  In this case, `A` and `B` are the same things, you just started with a different formula.

Comment: I didn't think we marked things as duplicates just because the answers were the same if the questions were different.  Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Gnome We do when they're asking about the exact same thing, even if they don't know what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable elective mode. You enable it through the options menu:

After enabling it, you can put any *active* skill in any active skill slot, which is the main attack (left mouse button), secondary attach (right mouse button) and the four active skills (1-4 keys).

You can, through key binding, change the default keys for the skills.

[image: pic]

[Picture source and explanation](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Use-Diablo-3-s-Elective-Mode-to-Equip-Any-Skills-You-Want-269828.shtml)

Comment: What do you mean "use Teleport in the same way as in Diablo II." @ceving?